# How to add multiple child Dijit Widget to a LayoutContainer efficiently?

Tags: javascript, performance, dojo, addchild

I have the basic scenario on a Dojo 1.9 + Dijit web application:

1. Request JSON data over the network
2. On the the successful reply I parse the JSON data and save to the application model
3. The UI watches the model and when there's data, it creates new Custom `dijit/_WidgetBase` instances to show the data.
4. Every Custom Dijit Widget is inserted to a `dijit/layout/LayoutContainer` via `myLayoutContainer.addChild(customWidget);`

Everything works fine but I would like to improve the rendering performance.
I noticed that `dijit/layout/LayoutContainer` is a `dijit/_Container` and has its own addChild() which uses `dojo/dom-construct.place()` which changes the DOM directly.

So I guess I could save some milliseconds if I add all my customWidget instances to a Document Fragment and then add it to the LayoutContainer with just one call to addChild().

But `dijit/_Container.addChild` requires a widget of type `dijit/_WidgetBase` so the Document Fragment approach wouldn't work.

How could I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a single "container" widget which contains all the logic to create the child widgets and attach it to itself.  Then only add the single "parent" widget to the LayoutContainer.  If you wanted to do even less you could just use a ContentPane as the "container" widget.

```
var contentPane = new ContentPane();
//multiple times
contentPane.addChild(...)
/layoutContainer in the page flow
layoutContainer.addChild(contentPane);
```

I can't comment as to how this would change performance though.